# Janusgraph ghost vertex

Tags: janusgraph

Our service runs a lot of concurrent updates and deletions of vertices in Janusgraph.

Sometimes we got odd vertices that has `vertex` label and not all related properties and edges. Sometimes this vertices have only one property (of three mandatory) or one edge and none of the properties. From our business logic this vertex looks like inconsistent and corrupted. Looking through the service logs I can't see specific errors or something abnormal related to this vertex ids.

Trying to remove such vertices

- sometimes we got errors like:

```
2020-12-23 15:57:09 ERROR StandardJanusGraph:750 - Could not commit transaction [2] due to storage exception in commit
org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
```

- sometimes we get success result of deletion but vertex is not actually removed and is still present in the graph.

Searching the Janusgraph documentation I found the notion of [ghost vertices](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/common-questions/#ghost-vertices)

> When the same vertex is concurrently removed in one transaction and modified in another, both transactions will successfully commit on eventually consistent storage backends and the vertex will still exist with only the modified properties or edges. This is referred to as a ghost vertex.

Also I found that there is `GhostVertexRemover` class in Janusgraph repository that intended to be run to  remove such vertexes.

Still have doubts if corrupted vertices that we have are ghost vertices described in documentation.

Comment: Which storage backend did you use? Are the concurrent updates and deletions of vertices happening within the same JVM? I assume ConsistencyModifier.LOCK works only within the same JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Have invested decent time into the investigation of this issue and here is the conclusions

First of all we did face ghost vertices. Usually they don't have label if you graph has static labels. ("vertex" label is provided dynamically by the code of Janusgraph). Ghost vertex will contain only those elements (properties or edges) that were updated during collision with concurrent delete of this vertex.
Original documentation states the same but in more concise way

> the vertex will still exist with only the modified properties or edges

[Here is the test that easily reproduces this issue](https://github.com/Playtika/aerospike-janusgraph-storage-backend/blob/develop/aerospike-storage-backend/src/test/java/com/playtika/janusgraph/aerospike/InconsistencyTest.java)

**How to mitigate the issue?**

Janusgraph documentation offers 2 options:

- periodically clean-up graph by `GhostVertexRemover` job

> A more scalable approach is to allow ghost vertices temporarily and clearing them out in regular time intervals.

- or configure transaction to detect such vertices

> Another option is to detect them at read-time using the option checkInternalVertexExistence() documented in Transaction

Both of this options do  not fit our needs.

- Ghost vertexes that present in graph even temporarily causes exceptions in our code.
- `checkInternalVertexExistence()` method is not accessible via tinkerpop transactions

**Solution**

*No more ghost vertices!*

This workaround helped us to resolve this issue with ghost vertices and didn't add any significant overhead in terms of code or performance.
You should add version property with lock consistency to all potentially ghost vertices (that may be concurrently updated and deleted). That property should be updated each time the vertex is modified (property or edge added)

*Define schema for VERSION property and SOURCE vertex*

```
PropertyKey versionPropertyKey = management.makePropertyKey(VERSION).dataType(Long.class).make();
management.setConsistency(versionPropertyKey , ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
management.addProperties(management.getVertexLabel(SOURCE), versionPropertyKey);
```

*Increment version property while adding edge*

```
Edge edge = traversal.addE(RELATION).from(traversal.V(sourceVertexId).property(VERSION, sourceVersion++))
                    .to(traversal.V(targetVertexId).property(VERSION, targetVersion++)).next();
```

*Increment version while updating vertex properties*

```
traversal.V(vertexId).next().property(VERSION, version++).property(OID, oidPropertyValue);
```

[Here you can find above mentioned examples that fixes this issue](https://github.com/Playtika/aerospike-janusgraph-storage-backend/blob/develop/aerospike-storage-backend/src/test/java/com/playtika/janusgraph/aerospike/InconsistencyTest.java)